# Creating a Hamburger menu in React

Tags: reactjs

Hopefully this is a really simple one, but I'm struggling to understand why there are such complicated answers out there. I'm converting a website across to React from plain HTML/CSS/JS at the moment. In there, you have, as an example - an external Vanilla JS file which has the code required to make the hamburger menu open and close.

Like so:

```js
// Variables

let line1 = document.getElementById("hamburger-line-1");
let line2 = document.getElementById("hamburger-line-2");
let hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
let navList = document.getElementById("hamburger-nav-list");


// Function

function hamburgerActive() {
  line1.classList.toggle("active");
  line2.classList.toggle("active");
  navList.classList.toggle("active");
}

// Event Listener

hamburger.addEventListener("click", hamburgerActive);
```

Now with React, I've rendered the header, which has the hamburger menu in it. This is stored in a index.js file, with a separate  component imported and rendered from a 'Header.js' file.

How do I go about transferring the vanilla JS into my Header component? Would the best way to approach it be to add a 'onclick' to the Header component in the Header.js file?

All the alternatives out there are talking about introducing props, states etc - that to me feels way too complicated for what is a really simple vanilla JS action. There must be a simple way of just putting this code in and making it work?

For reference, here is the Header component as is:

```js
class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (


      <header className="universal-header-section">
        <div className="universal-header-container">
          <div className="universal-header-hamburger">
            <div id="hamburger">
              <span id="hamburger-line-1" class="hamburger-span" />
              <span id="hamburger-line-2" class="hamburger-span" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="universal-header-logo">
            <a href="index">
              <h2>TBC</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="universal-header-basket">
            <a href="basket">
              <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hamburger-nav-list">
          <div class="hamburger-container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

Can somebody advise or will I have to use props/state?

Thanks. Hopefully that all makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use state, it is designed for stuff like this:

using a functional component like so:

```
const Header = () => {

   const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true) // you could default to false

    return (
// this will toggle the state to be true/false (opposite to the previous one) then
based on that you can add certain classes to either show or hide it

      <header className="universal-header-section" onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>
        <div className="universal-header-container">
          <div className="universal-header-hamburger">
            <div id="hamburger">
              <span id="hamburger-line-1" class=`hamburger-span ${toggle ? 'active' : ''} ` />
              <span id="hamburger-line-2" class=`hamburger-span ${toggle ? 'active' : ''} ` />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="universal-header-logo">
            <a href="index">
              <h2>TBC</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="universal-header-basket">
            <a href="basket">
              <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hamburger-nav-list">
          <div class="hamburger-container">

          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

you can add a new class name like this:

```
<div className={`myClass toggle ? "active" : ''}></div>
```

this code is saying if `toggle` is true, then add `active` to this class, if not, add ''. so you can add this to the classes that need to change `onClick`

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm new to React (you can probably tell), so don't know too much about this really. So I'm needing multiple 'active' classes to be added when you click on the hamburger. How would I do that? Wouldn't it all need to come under a function which is added as a click event?

Comment: If you need multiple then you can reuse the logic I’ve used in the second snippet. You can listen to the same state for as many divs/elements as you like and toggle as many to be active or inactive as you like. Let me update the code, one sec

Comment: so I've added it here: `<span id="hamburger-line-1" class=`hamburger-span ${toggle ? 'active' : ''} ` />` im basically saying if `toggle` is true then add `active` class. does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense - thank you. I'm *hoping* it works, only issue is setToggle const isn't working - is it definitely right? Seen a few variations on google but just checking since you know what you're talking about.

Comment: when you say not working, how exactly? if you `console.log(toggle)` is it showing true/false everytime you click?

Comment: Apologies - I've figured it out now. Thank you a lot for your help!